# LiPo charger module for 5.2V/2-3A load

Tags: battery-charging, raspberry-pi, lipo

I have a load (more specifically a Raspberry Pi 3 B) which requires a voltage of 5.2V and needs around 2-3A current. It should be powered by a LiPo battery with a capacity of 6000 mAh. In addition to that, the battery should be chargeable with a power supply (in less than 6 hours) and at the same time power the load.

As far as I've understood I first need a DC-DC booster to reach 5.2V but also a charger module that is safe.
I cannot build such a module from scratch because LiPo powering can be quite dangerous and I'm not a battery expert.
But it seems like there is not such a module to buy online, especially when it comes to the 5.2V/2-3A requirements of the load.

Now my question is: Is there actually a way to achieve all this? And if yes, which components do I need to build a charger with an integrated booster?

Comment: How dynamic is the load?  motor?  USB hub?  get a laptop battery and run it with its own charger and https://www.banggood.com/Dual-USB-Output-6-24V-To-5_2V-3A-DC-DC-Step-Down-Power-Charger-Module-Converter-p-1092047.html?cur_warehouse=CN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into LiPo packs that are used in many RC applications, such as the ones available [here](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/batteries/lipo-batteries-all-brands.html). These packs consist of multiple cells wired in series, which you could then regulate down instead of boosting. These cells typically have a very high discharge rate, much higher than you'll ever need to power a Pi, and are available in some very high capacities. You can also purchase chargers for your cells here, and since these products are targeted at RC hobbyists, there are  many pre-built options for regulation, monitoring, distribution, etc.